# Getting current URL without Selenium

Tags: python, url, browser, google-oauth

I am attempting to extract an authorization code from an Oauth2 redirect URI.

I.E. once one of my users clicks allow on an Oauth2 consent form, they are redirected back to my indicated URL - but with an important authorization code in the parameters. For example:

```
http://localhost:5000/account?code=authorization_code
```

I know I can use Selenium Webdriver to grab the URL, but I have to eventually deploy this to my Linux server.

My question is, how can I pull the current user URL from the browser such that I can use it for my purposes?

(I am also open to other suggestions for how to approach this if there are better alternatives)

Comment: if it is autorization for your page then in Google you should set `http://yourdomain/your_function` and then Google will redirect to `http://yourdomain/your_function?code=authorization_code` and then you can get this code in your function.

Comment: @furas It is authorization to access a users API credentials. How do I pass the code to my function?

Comment: if this is your page (in Django, Flask) then you can get it in function `account` in your project

Comment: @furas Yes I am using Flask. So you are saying the code is already available? Where is it stored?

Comment: create function with `@app.route('/account')` and in this function you should get it with `request.args.get('code')`

Comment: @furas This is sort of working, but when I try to print out the code it is returning "none"

Comment: did you run url with `?code=authorization_code` ? if not then `get('code')` gives `None` because it can't find `code=` in url.

Comment: @furas Thank you, this worked. Wish I could give you more points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is your page  in `Flask` then you can use `request.args.get('code')` to get it in function created with `@app.route('/account')`

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/account')
def account():
    code = request.args.get('code')
    print('code:', code)
    return "Your code: " + code

app.run()
```

If you use in browser `http://localhost:5000/account?code=1234567890` then it will send it to your Flask and it will display `1234567890` in console/terminal and `"Your code: 1234567890"` on page.